# Dealing with Many Tables with Identical/Similar Schemas AND Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, schema

We've got an interesting requirement that many tables with text have to supply those values in all the languages the user has configured for their installation (and we're not supporting right-to-left text). It's an ASP.NET MVC web app with Entity Framework.

Typically, these are lookup/dropdown lists that clients manage and they need to be able to view various screens and select which language is displayed (and I'm not even talking about label text yet)

Where I'd normally have a bunch (dozens in this case) of tables with this layout:

```
ID int PK,
Display nvarchar(100),
<other stuff>
```

I've now got 2 tables:

```
Master Table
ID int PK,
<other stuff>

Language Table
ID int PK FK to corresponding master table
LangID int PK FK to table of implements languages
Display nvarchar(100)
```

Say I have 3 languages and an OptionA table with 4 rows, I end up with:
    OptionA - 4 rows
    OptionA_L - 12 rows

... and then I've got ~60 of those table pairs.

All the *_L tables have the same core columns (above) and some may have additional text columns (notes, alternate name, etc).

First, the *_L concept isn't carved in stone - it's just what I've come up with so far.

Second, we're using Entity Framework 6, database-first. These tables would be fairly easy to deal with if we were just building SQL statements and could substitute table names with text. I see you can execute SQL via EF, but it's limited and doesn't help here. Plus, I'd rather do something more elegant. I would think a common interface would help, but I haven't figured out how yet. So I've got lot's of duplicated code and a few gigantic switch statements.

So, specifically:

1. Is the schema/*_L plan reasonable? (reasonableness of the requirement aside!)
2. My SQL2008/2012 knowledge is pretty superficial - tables and columns and such. Does its XML or CLR support help me in any way?
3. It does seem I should be able to leverage an interface or generics - but doing so in the context of EF data contexts eludes me. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want [Table Per Type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

I often use an abstract base class to add the Id column to each table.

```
public abstract class BasicBo
{
   public virtual int Id {get;set;
}

public class Thing :BasicBo
{
    // other properties.
}

public class MyDbContext( string connectionString) :  base(connectionString)
{
   public DbSet<Thing> Things { get;set;}
   // etc
}
```

Comment: We ended up changing the design, but this might help there as well.
Thanks